# API calls to my server fail randomly [FastAPI]

Tags: azure, sqlalchemy, fastapi, pg8000

My usual response time is <50ms. Here's my tech:

- Web Server: FastAPI+uvicorn
- Proxy: nginx
- DB: Postgres on VM
- DB API: sqlalchemy+pg8000

There are two docker containers (~1GB) running on the VM.

However, the request wouldn't reach the server, and would timeout with 404 with the following exception (not reproducible):

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InterfaceError: (pg8000.exceptions.InterfaceError) network error
```

All servers are [Azure D series](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/dv3-dsv3-series) VMs and in the same VNET.

I've had this issue previously, which I was able to solve by having only one docker on that VM. However, in this case both images are lightweight.

Comment: Impossible to answer without more details, [the error seems to imply a network issue though](https://pybrary.net/pg8000/errors.html)

Comment: yes, I also feel it has less to do with code -- how do we solve network errors? I assumed having the same VNET with premium VM will do that.

Comment: Try using version 1.29.5 as this fixes a bug which would give the error you're seeing.

Comment: @TonyLocke thanks for replying. Can you please send any related links (I tried to look up) that explains this bug. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a recent bug fix in [pg8000](https://pypi.org/project/pg8000/) version 1.29.5 that may fix the problem you're seeing. Looking at the [release notes](https://pypi.org/project/pg8000/#version-1-29-5-2023-05-09) the relevant bit is:

> Fixed bug where pg8000 didn’t handle the case when the number of bytes
> received from a socket was fewer than requested. This was being
> interpreted as a network error, but in fact we just needed to wait
> until more bytes were available.

and the [commit itself](https://github.com/tlocke/pg8000/commit/a84bf8c7b68abd0966b12d24bf481c0018e0cd87) may be helpful.